# Safe to uninstall Postini from Google Apps?

Tags: email, gmail, google-workspace

I'm trying to add a domain to Google Apps so I can forward its email to a gmail address. When I try to add the domain, though, I get this error message:

`Postini services curently only support a single domain. Please remove the service to add additional domains.`

There's a link to a page where I can uninstall Postini services, but I'm afraid this will screw up my company's gmail and related apps (there are about twenty emails being used). Does anyone know if it's safe to uninstall Postini?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is on topic for Super User.

Comment: @DragonLord where do you recommend posting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same question and doing some research I found that Google is getting rid of Postini. I uninstalled and have had no side effects.

They have a comprehensive transition guide that you can follow.
http://postini-transition.googleapps.com/